# logic apps integration with Vnet

Tags: azure-logic-apps, vnet

I need to integrate my Logic Apps with a VNet, i've find this article :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-isolated-environment#create-environment

But can't find more the ISE on Azure Marketplace, any idea please ?

Regards,

Comment: Hi did you get this resolved I am trying to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

ISE is a preview service enabled on demand and only in specific regions.

> Quote from Microsoft: This capability is in private preview. To
>   request access, create your request to join [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-isolated-environment-overview).
>
> Note that Integration Service Environment private preview is only
>   available in Australia East, West Europe, West US 2, East US but will
>   be in all Logic App regions for public preview.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your ISE via Azure portal and use it. You will have multiple skus to have. Developer or premium.
The developer a cannot be used in production and causes throttling after particular number of actions fired./time unit.

This is a dedicated environment for u with better performance than normal consumption. Still this is expensive.

Alternatively you can use logic apps standard. Vnet integrated veriosn of logic apps.